# vector / matrix library for OpenGL ES 2.x app

Tags: opengl-es, ios4

I'm looking for a free 3D vector / matrix library that handles canonical operations ala the OpenGL specification and GLU (dot, cross, rotations, translations, inversions, look at, etc).  This will be used with ES 2.x+ apps.  GLU and GLUT are not available.

Platform is iphone OS 4.1 sdk.

Seems like a waste of time to write one of these from scratch but will if necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the source to GLU and port it yourself. it's really just a matter of changing double to float and including it in your project.